# .htaccess RewriteRule duplicate Query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, formatting

I found several topics related to my problem on **stackoverflow.com**, but I have not found the solution yet.

This is my **.htaccess** code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^library-(.*)\.aspx$ index.php?page=library&image=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^information-(.*)\.aspx$ index.php?page=information&text=$1[NC,L,QSA]
```

Great, the new **formatting of URLs** works :

https://example.com/library-image5000.aspx
or
https://example.com/information-sometext.aspx

But, can anyone tell me **why the url accept the both of query strings?**

https://example.com/library-image5000.aspx/information-sometext.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your regex pattern `^library-(.*)\.aspx$` also matches the URI `/library-image5000.aspx/information-sometext.aspx` .

You can use use a restricted pattern instead of the catch-all `(.*)` .  Use `([^/]+)`as it matches any characters except `/` .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^library-([^/]+)\.aspx$ index.php?page=library&image=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^information-([^/]+)\.aspx$ index.php?page=information&text=$1[NC,L,QSA]
```